# Rounded Slider corner ios

Tags: ios

How can I make my slide bar's corner rounded in IOS?I have round image and I set it .But the corners are still showing square.
Is there any method using which I can set my slider's corner bounds?
Please Help me.
.Thanks in advance..

Comment: Show what you have done so far. Include the image(s) you used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try use it:

```
float radius = 10;
CALayer * l = [yourControl layer];
[l setMasksToBounds:YES];
[l setCornerRadius:radius];
```

You may import QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h

**Swift 2.2 Version**

```
let radius: CGFloat = 10.0
let myControlLayer: CALayer = self.myControl.layer
myControlLayer.masksToBounds = true
myControlLayer.cornerRadius = radius
```